# Applescript paste CSV contents to web form

Tags: javascript, macros, applescript, import-from-csv

I've created a macro in Excel that creates a CSV file which is named test[date/time].csv the macro then passes the data/time to an applescript.

What I want that applescript to do is to copy the contents of the CSV file and paste it into a webform. I can copy the CSV contents (i've tried it through keystrokes and copying to clipboard too) but I cannot get it copy the file contents into the web form UNLESS it is only one line - in which case it works fine. I know it must have something to do with the carriage returns or something, but I can't figure it out. Please help!

Here's my code

```
on run argv
    set fileNameTime to (item 1 of argv)
    set fileName to "Test" & fileNameTime & ".csv"

    tell application "Finder"
        set myFolder to container of (path to me) as text
    end tell

    set srcFileString to (myFolder & fileName)
    set theFileReference to open for access srcFileString
    set CSVText to read theFileReference
    close access theFileReference

    tell application "Safari"

        open location "https://www.internalbusinesswebsite.com"
        delay 2
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('issue-import-csv').value = '" & CSVText & "';" in document 1

    end tell
end run
```